# WSL Not Starting in VS Code - tried updating it, wsl shutdown, and restarting computer

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm getting this error regarding WSL2 not starting. I've tried doing `wsl --shutdown` `wsl` in PowerShell and restarting my computer but it's still not running. The state in PowerShell says it's running, though, I am still getting the error. If I open Ubuntu in Windows and run `code .` that doesn't work either. I've updated wsl to the latest version. Thanks for your help!

```
[2023-01-23 06:26:26.345] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (wsl2)
[2023-01-23 06:26:26.345] Extension version: 0.72.0
[2023-01-23 06:26:26.345] Windows build: 19044. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2023-01-23 06:26:26.346] No shell environment set or found for current distro.
[2023-01-23 06:26:26.507] WSL daemon log file: 
[2023-01-23 06:26:26.510] Probing if server is already installed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e sh -c "[ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534 ] && printf found || ([ -f /etc/alpine-release ] && printf alpine-; uname -m)"
[2023-01-23 06:26:29.965] Probing result: found
[2023-01-23 06:26:29.966] Server install found in WSL
[2023-01-23 06:26:29.967] Launching C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" 97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534 stable code-server .vscode-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=1837640582-1523319798-660006518-1171681990 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all'
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.216] Setting up server environment: Looking for /home/samtimus/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.216] WSL version: 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 Ubuntu
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.216] WSL-shell-PID: 13
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.216] Node executable: /home/samtimus/.vscode-server/bin/97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534/node
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.216] Starting server: /home/samtimus/.vscode-server/bin/97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534/bin/code-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=1837640582-1523319798-660006518-1171681990 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.217] VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly.
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.217] For help with startup problems, go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.222] C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e kill 13
[2023-01-23 06:26:30.546] WSL Daemon exited with code 0

PS C:\Users\User> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2

PS C:\Users\User> wsl --update
Checking for updates.
The most recent version of Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out with the following steps!

Within the WSL terminal, type rm -r ~/.vscode-server to delete the VS Code WSL server. Exit the terminal and from your PowerShell/Cmd, run wsl --shutdown . Then you can log in back to your WSL and run code . and it should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed your sub-system (UBUNTU) the system created a shortcut to having direct access to the shell.

If you don't, open your PowerShell and exec BASH. If still don't, open your VSCODE on windows.

Install the extension [WSL EXTENSION](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl).

Open a WSL terminal window (using the start menu item or by typing wsl from a command prompt / PowerShell.

Another way is. Open your VSCODE on windows, press F1 and select **WSL: New WSL Window.**

Comment: So I had the extension installed already and I tried executing wsl from Powershell. WSL: New WSL Window doesn't work either.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with the following steps! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386836/wsl2-vscodes-shell-command-code-no-longer-working-in-linux-terminal#:~:text=Within%20the%20WSL%20terminal%2C%20type,and%20it%20should%20work%20normally.

Within the WSL terminal, type rm -r ~/.vscode-server to delete the VS Code WSL server.

Exit the terminal and from your PowerShell/Cmd, run wsl --shutdown . Then you can log in back to your WSL and run code . and it should work normally.